# How to programatically change the color of a Drawable without coloring alpha pixels

Tags: android, colors, drawable, alpha

My Drawables have a transparent background with an white icon in the middle. What I want to do is programatically color ONLY the white part and leave the transparent pixels untouched.

I've tried lots of different methods but I always end up with a Drawable that is completly colored.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it will suit your requirement, but please split the one image with two, one full background transparent image and other is single white image icon and put this on the centre of the layout and change only that imageicon's color.

Comment: Thanks, but this would mean I would get a colored square in the middle. It would not make a white star icon a red star icon, it would make it a red square (for me).